# Java application creates empty error.log on program start

Tags: java, eclipse, printstream

I want my application to create an error.log if, and only if, an error occurs. So I did this:

```
System.setErr(new PrintStream("error.log"));
```

Works as expected in Eclipse - error happens, error.log with error message pops up in the source dir.. The exported application, however, creates a completely empty log file right on program start, which is annoying. What's the reason for this behavior?

Comment: It's always supposed to create the file (or recreate if already exists). What exactly do you expect? Your test on Ecplise is incomplete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [`PrintStream` docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#PrintStream%28java.lang.String%29):

> `fileName` - The name of the file to use as the destination of this print stream. If the file exists, then it will be truncated to zero size; **otherwise, a new file will be created.** The output will be written to the file and is buffered.

This code creates the file in my version of NetBeans. You could create the `PrintStream` on the first error, instead of creating it no matter what.

Comment: Creating the PrintStream when it's needed sounds like a good idea, but how can I do that? Using System.setErr seemed like such an easy solution, since everything gets done automatically..

Comment: One way is to create a thin wrapper class with a `PrintStream` member that it initializes on the first error instead of directly calling `System.err` methods.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the PrintStream api

When you call `new PrintStream` if the `error.log` file does not exist, it will create it.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#PrintStream(java.lang.String)

> fileName - The name of the file to use as the destination of this
>   print stream. If the file exists, then it will be truncated to zero
>   size; otherwise, a new file will be created. The output will be
>   written to the file and is buffered.